# I need a custom confirm box to be implemented in html form Onsubmit().How can i implement this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a custom confirm box to be implemented on html form Onsubmit().How can i implement this?

Something like this

```
 <form method="post"  style="float:left" action="xxx/**"
     onsubmit="return confirmfinish()"
```

confirmfinish() should implement the custom confirm box and return the appropriate value(true/false)

Comment: Is using jQuery UI modal an option?  Or `window.confirm`?

Comment: You can use jquery for this http://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/

Comment: @devang Rathod:I have used the same code but the problem here is the form get posted without waiting for the user input from confirm box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery UI like this it's below

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete Country">
    <p>
        Are you soure you wont to delete this record ?</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {           
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            model: true,
            width: 300,
            resizable: false,
            height: 200
        });

        $(".lnkDelete").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var targeturl = $(this).attr("href");


            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                buttons: {
                    "Confirm": function () {
                        window.location.href = targeturl;
                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
        });
    });
</script>
```

i think this will help you......

Answer (score 1):

I took your FORM tag example and tweaked it some as seen below. This will let you do a custom confirm. It will stop the form from submitting until you click Yes on the custom confirm.

```
<form id="mainForm" method="post" action="xxx/**" onsubmit="return confirmfinish();">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<div id="confirmationDiv" style="display:none; border:1px solid black; padding:10px; margin-top:10px; width:500px;">
    Are you sure you want to submit the form?<br>
    <input type="button" value="Yes" onclick="confirmed = true; document.getElementById('mainForm').submit();">
    <input type="button" value="No" onclick="document.getElementById('confirmationDiv').style.display='none'; return false;">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">     
    var confirmed = false;

    function confirmfinish(){
        if(!confirmed){
            document.getElementById('confirmationDiv').style.display='block';
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of showing and hiding a DIV like in my example, you can show and hide a custom popup.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code out which I have based on your code:

```
<form method="post" action="xxx/**" onsubmit="return confirmfinish();">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmfinish(){
        return confirm("Are you sure you are ready to submit the form?");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: but I need custom confirm box

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this .

```
function confirmfinish(){
     if (confirm("Your question")) { 
          // do things if OK
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the inbuilt support of javascript for confirm box like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmfinish(){
       if (confirm("Are you sure you want Submit the form?") == true)
           return true;
       else 
           return false;
    }
    </script>
```

or

If you only need to implement custom controls for it instead of inbuilt support from javascript

Go a head and click this link of [jQuery Alert Dialogs (Alert, Confirm, & Prompt Replacements)](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/)

Inorder to implement jAlert you need to have `jquery.jalerts.js` file and add the following code to your confirmfinish()

```
jConfirm('Submit form?', 'Submitting the form', function(r) {
    jAlert('Confirmed: ' + r, 'Confirmation Results');
});
```

Hope it helps